# What could cause latency between two VMs on the same physical server?

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, dns, virtual-machine

I have a web VM and a database VM on the same physical server (Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V). The web site is a classic ASP site on a Windows 2012 server, and the database is on SQL Server 2012, also on Windows Server 2012.

My colo has a DNS server (not used for these VMs), and when it goes down, the site experiences Script Timeout errors -- the pages take 180+ seconds to process. When inspecting the site profiling, many of the database calls are taking several seconds each.

However, the SQL profile shows no performance issues -- all queries take only a few milliseconds to process. Putting a filter of 1,000+ milliseconds shows no matching results. So this leads me to believe the latency is between the web and database VMs.

However, this makes no sense for several reasons:

- The DNS server does not host and entries related to this site or database.
- All connections use IPs, not domain/machine names.
- The latency is between the two VMs, but these are on the same server, so network issues should not impact the communication between the VMs. I verified this by running Wireshark, no web-to-DB traffic hits the NIC.

What could be causing this?

**Edit:**
Forgot that the DNS server does have a reverse DNS for the IP and site domain. But still can't imagine how this would result in the latency between the web and DB VMs.

**Additional details in response to comments:**

The MDAC version, according to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=301202), is 6.2.9200.16384. I don't remember installing MDAC separately, so I'm assuming it's what comes installed w/ Windows Server 2012.

They are on the same subnet. A `tracert` shows a direct route from the web server to the DB server.

Here is the connection string:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=[DbServerIp];Integrated Security=SSPI;Network=DBMSSOCN
```

This is *not* running VMWare, but instead is Windows Hyper-V. Thought I mentioned that before, but I see now that I didn't (have now added it above).

Comment: Classic ASP?  MDAC 2.6?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300420

Comment: "The latency is between the two VMs" - Are they on the same subnet? Run a tracert between the two, are they one hop?

Comment: Can we see the Conn String?

Comment: I have updated the OP w/ answers to these comments.

Comment: Can you clarify what Hypervisor and version are running please, e.g. ESXi 5.0?

Comment: I've added additional details above. This is Hyper-V, not VMWare.

Comment: Try not using integrated security. Example:
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=YOUR_SQL_IP_ADDR;User ID=YOUR_SQL_LOGIN;Password=YOUR_SQL_PW;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DB_NAME

Comment: You should attach to the process with Visual Studio when it's experiencing these issues and see where the scripts are spinning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291223(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: have you tried adding a manual entry in your hosts file for the local (internal) address of your sql server?   My point is, have you tried avoiding using DNS all together?

Comment: @Frank unfortunately, I'm pretty sure it's not a DNS issue, as I'm using IPs only in the connections.

Comment: @JeradRose, note that DNS is during authentication when Windows authentication is used.  Like dmarietta suggested, you could avoid the dependency with SQL authentication.  Alternatively, use secondary DNS servers and multiple domain controllers, if possible.

Comment: Try adding ;Pooling=True to your connection string and try it again. This will prevent SQL connections being opened/closed on each query and should offer some performance benefit

Answer (score 0):

I think the following link may resolve your very issue:

[Read thread to the bottom to disable the NETBIOS Helper](http://forums.iis.net/t/1201363.aspx?How%20set%20IIS%207%205%20to%20not%20timeout%20when%20rDNS%20record%20is%20not%20available%20)

Essentially, as odd as it sounds, try disabling NETBIOS  on your network adapter(s):

[image]